# setup.* files upon 3rd party install

Tags: ros, 3rd-party-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [REP-0136](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0136.html) I took that `Have setup.* Files After Installation` is one of a few required steps for the 3rd parth release from upstream repository. But what are `setup.*` files? Are they setup.*sh or setup.py? I also appreciate if someone points me to existing examples.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219424/setup.*-files-upon-3rd-party-install/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2015-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They are setup.bash/sh/zsh etc. They are not required if your package installs into the standard locations and does not need to setup environment.

They are there to let the packages export things into your environment to allow the packages to function on your system such that when you source your setup.* from the workspace you will get the packages things like an extended library path etc.

For an example see opencv3 [here](https://github.com/ros-gbp/opencv3-release)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0